# Descobrir endereço de Broadcast para envio de mensagem UDP

Tags: c#, socket

A minha interface de rede Wi-Fi contém as seguintes configurações:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::95d7:bda0:eac3:ebf7%5
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Uma forma de eu enviar uma stream de texto é recorrendo ao protocolo UDP.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Socket emissor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    IPAddress destinatario = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255");
    IPEndPoint emissor_end_point = new IPEndPoint(destinatario, 33333);

    Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem a enviar:");
    string mensagem = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] mensagem_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensagem);

    emissor.SendTo(mensagem_buffer, emissor_end_point);
    emissor.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Mensagem enviada ...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Tratando-se de um endereço ip de classe C, de forma a enviar a mensagem em *broadcast* basta alterar o último octeto para 255.

É possível obter este endereço de ip automaticamente, independentemente a rede onde o programa é executado?

Queria evitar o processo "fastidioso" de fazer tratamento de texto com as strings associadas ao ip e respetiva máscara.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que vc quer, seria obter o endereço de IP de um computador da rede de forma automática?

Comment: voce quer enviar uma mensagem em broadcast para que todos hosts conectado na rede recebam e isso?

Comment: Sim ... mas não quero ter que escrever o ip da rede onde estou no código.

Comment: se voce estiver querendo obter a mascara de rede automaticamente eu nao sei se com socket e possivel mas com threads do sistema provavelmente sim

Comment: Também me estou a esquecer de que um host pode ter mais do que uma interface ... o que complica ainda mais o cenário.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Socket emissor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    // IPAddress destinatario = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255");
    udpSocket.EnableBroadcast = true;
    IPAddress destinatario = IPAddress.Broadcast
    IPEndPoint emissor_end_point = new IPEndPoint(destinatario, 33333);

    Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem a enviar:");
    string mensagem = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] mensagem_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensagem);

    emissor.SendTo(mensagem_buffer, emissor_end_point);
    emissor.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Mensagem enviada ...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Refrencia [Socket.EnableBroadcast Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.enablebroadcast%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Campo IPAddress.Broadcast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.ipaddress.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Um outro exemplo de codigo muito mal escrito tirado do site [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tst0kwb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para receber datagramas **UDP**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class UDPListener 
{
    private const int listenPort = 11000;

    private static void StartListener() 
    {
        bool done = false;

        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,listenPort);

        try 
        {
            while (!done) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive( ref groupEP);

                Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast from {0} :\n {1}\n",
                    groupEP.ToString(),
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytes.Length));
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }

    public static int Main() 
    {
        StartListener();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Deixo a minha versão final do emissor/recetor elementar.

**Emissor**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declarações
        int porto = 33333;
        Socket emissor = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress destinatario = IPAddress.Broadcast;
        emissor.EnableBroadcast = true;
        IPEndPoint emissorEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(destinatario, porto);

        // Enviar mensagem
        Console.WriteLine("Digite a mensagem a enviar:");
        string mensagem = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] mensagemBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mensagem);
        emissor.SendTo(mensagemBuffer, emissorEndPoint);
        emissor.Close();

        //Terminar ...
        Console.WriteLine("Mensagem enviada\nPrima uma tecla para continuar ...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Recetor**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        //Declarações
        int porto = 33333;
        UdpClient recetor = new UdpClient(porto);
        IPEndPoint escutaEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, porto);
        string mensagem;
        byte[] recebidoByteArray;

        //Receção
        Console.WriteLine("A aguardar chegada de mensagem em broadcast...");
        recebidoByteArray = recetor.Receive(ref escutaEndPoint);
        mensagem = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recebidoByteArray, 0, recebidoByteArray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("[Mensagem recebida a {0} ] {1}", DateTime.Now, mensagem);
        recetor.Close();

        // Terminar ...
        while (Console.KeyAvailable) Console.ReadKey(false);
        Console.WriteLine("Prima uma tecla para continuar ...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
}
```